# VB.NET/Access - SELECT SUM SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a table with LastName, FirstName, Wins, Losses, CompFormat and Medals columns.  In case the person who told me not to use pictures on my last question sees this I tried your suggestion and couldn't figure it out so I have to use pictures.  So don't bite my head off this time.  I successfully added and grouped Wins with CompFormat like this...

```
("SELECT SUM(Wins) AS Total, FirstName, LastName, CompFormat FROM CompetitionDate GROUP BY LastName, FirstName, CompFormat;")
```

Which correctly produced this in my datagridview...

[image: Correct Outcome]

Instead of what I did I want to add counting losses and group it to look like this

[image]

Here is my access table...

[image]

Comment: Pictures are still bad. Work harder at formatting the data. Browse some other questions tagged SQL and use the "`edit`" or "`improve this question`" link to see the raw source for how they did it.

Comment: Nah.  I will ask my questions how I want to ask them or go somewhere else for help.

Comment: If pictures are bad then why do you have the option of adding them?  If they are bad then just take the option away.  I am not going to spend hours figuring out how to format a question so that I don't have to show picture.  I am new to this which is why I come here and I don't have time to research asking questions in a way that makes others happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add the `Losses` column:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CompFormat,
       SUM(Wins) AS Wins, SUM(Losses) as Losses
FROM CompetitionDate
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName, CompFormat
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  That worked.  I was getting hung up on the syntax of the second SUM.  I was overthinking the examples I found.